# Second Flux does never start to do its work

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I wanted to test spring reactor and for that I implemented a small example, here is the relevant code:

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceData data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.data.start();
    }
}
```

FluxCreatorFunction

```
public class FluxCreatorFunction<T extends Function<V, E>, V, E> {

    public ConnectableFlux<E> createFlux(T t, V v) {
        return (ConnectableFlux<E>) Flux.<E>create(flux -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, (3 + 1)) * 1000));

                    flux.next(t.apply(v));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).publish();
    }   
}
```

ServiceData

```
@Service
public class ServiceData {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("inserter")
    private ConnectableFlux<Todo> fluxInserter;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("deleter")
    private ConnectableFlux<Todo> fluxDeleter;

    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository repo;

    public void start() {
        this.startInserter();
        this.startDeleter();
    }

    public void startInserter() {
        this.fluxInserter.subscribe(new ConsumerInserter());
        this.fluxInserter.subscribe((todo) -> {
            this.repo.save(todo);
            this.repo.flush();
        });

        this.fluxInserter.connect();
    }

    public void startDeleter() {
        this.fluxDeleter.subscribe(new ConsumerDeleter());
        this.fluxDeleter.subscribe((todo) -> {
            this.repo.delete(todo);
            this.repo.flush();
        });

        this.fluxDeleter.connect();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("inserter")
    public ConnectableFlux<Todo> createInserter() {
        return new FluxCreatorFunction<FunctionInserter, Void, Todo>().createFlux(new FunctionInserter(), null);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("deleter")
    public ConnectableFlux<Todo> createDeleter() {
        return new FluxCreatorFunction<FunctionDeleter, TodoRepository, Todo>().createFlux(new FunctionDeleter(), this.repo);
    }
}

class FunctionInserter implements Function<Void, Todo> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Override
    public Todo apply(Void v) {
        String quote = this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", QuoteResource.class).getValue().getQuote();

        return new Todo(quote, false);
    }
}

class FunctionDeleter implements Function<TodoRepository, Todo> {

    @Override
    public Todo apply(TodoRepository repo) {
        return repo.findAll().get(0);
    }
}

class ConsumerInserter implements Consumer<Todo> {

    @Override
    public void accept(Todo todo) {
        System.out.println("New todo: " + todo.getText());
    }
}

class ConsumerDeleter implements Consumer<Todo> {

    @Override
    public void accept(Todo todo) {
        System.out.println("Deleted todo: " + todo.getText());
    }
}
```

As you can see I am creating two different `Flux` publisher. Both are created as a `@Bean` and `@Autowired` to the service.

The problem is: Onlay the first `Flux` is doing its work. If I start the Inserter first:

```
this.startInserter();
this.startDeleter();
```

The output is:

```
New todo: So easy it is to switch container in #springboot.
New todo: Spring has come quite a ways in addressing developer enjoyment and ease of use since the last time I built an application using it.
New todo: Working with Spring Boot is like pair-programming with the Spring developers.
New todo: Spring has come quite a ways in addressing developer enjoyment and ease of use since the last time I built an application using it.
New todo: The real benefit of Boot, however, is that it's just Spring. That means any direction the code takes, regardless of complexity, I know it's a safe bet.
New todo: I have two hours today to build an app from scratch. @springboot to the rescue!
New todo: Really loving Spring Boot, makes stand alone Spring apps easy.
New todo: Really loving Spring Boot, makes stand alone Spring apps easy.
```

If I turn it around:

```
this.startDeleter();
this.startInserter();
```

The output is:

```
Deleted todo: Spring has come quite a ways in addressing developer enjoyment and ease of use since the last time I built an application using it.
Deleted todo: Spring has come quite a ways in addressing developer enjoyment and ease of use since the last time I built an application using it.
Deleted todo: The real benefit of Boot, however, is that it's just Spring. That means any direction the code takes, regardless of complexity, I know it's a safe bet.
Deleted todo: Spring has come quite a ways in addressing developer enjoyment and ease of use since the last time I built an application using it.
Deleted todo: So easy it is to switch container in #springboot.
Deleted todo: I have two hours today to build an app from scratch. @springboot to the rescue!
Deleted todo: Really loving Spring Boot, makes stand alone Spring apps easy.
Deleted todo: So easy it is to switch container in #springboot.
```

So it does not matter which `Flux` I start first. The second `Flux` is never doing its work and I have no idea why. Are both `Flux` running on the same thread? Do they need an identifier? What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you generate data inside `Flux.create` must be asynchronous. Here you are blocking, which is not supported. Yes, both `Flux` end up executing on the same thread and the first one indefinitely loops and blocks said thread.

You could use "subscribeOn" and a scheduler like `Schedulers.parallel()` or `Schedulers.elastic()` to defer the work on a separate thread.

You could also maybe try to avoid using `create/generate` and be entirely non blocking by using time operators. The latest 3.1.0.M2 milestone has `delayUntil`,
 for example. You could also use something like `Flux.range(1, n).concatMap(index -> Mono.delay(generateRandomDelayValue(index))`

Edit: A way I can think of to reproduce the random delay behavior you tried to put in place would be:

```
public class FluxCreatorFunction<T extends Function<V, E>, V, E> {

  public ConnectableFlux<E> createFlux(T t, V v) {
    //use generate to generate a random value per cycle
    return Flux.generate(sink -> ThreadLocalRandom
                                 .current()
                                 .nextInt(1, (3 + 1)))
               //that random value will be used as a delay, so we need to
               //transform each value into a new async sequence, and also
               //ensure that the order is preserved, hence concatMap
               .concatMap(randomDelay ->
                          //we introduce a delay then...
                          Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(randomDelay))
                              //... map to the result of the function
                              .map(ignore -> t.apply(v))
               .publish();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Do you know of any example showing how to do it?